# Zooming to feature not in center using OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, zoom

inside my webgis application with Ol3 I've to zoom to a single feature.

My problem is that I've a panel at the bottom of my screen over the Map div. So the zoomed features often finished half hidden by this panel. The result is like this:[image: red zoomed feature, hidden by the bottom panel]

Obviusly I want to see the whole feature when I zoom.
I tried this dirty workaround:

```
map.getView().fit(feature.getGeometry(), map.getSize());
var geom_centre = map.getView().getCenter(); 
var lon = geom_centre[1] - 50;
var north_centre = [geom_centre[0],lon];
map.getView().setCenter(north_centre);
map.getView().setZoom(map.getView().getZoom() - 1);
```

Essentially I made the "classical" zoom and then I move to north the centre of the view and go back of one zoom level. 
It doesn't work well because the features have different dimensions and I move them to north of arbitrary length (50) and the smallest features are pushed outside view to north.

How can I zoom to a feature and move it to north without push it outside the view?

Comment: Did you try using _padding_ option to fit() method? Adding a padding bottom with the height of your bottom panel should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass padding array to your map.getView().fit()

```
var panel = document.getElementById('yourPanelID'); //your panel element
var paddingTop = panel.offsetHeight;
var paddingRight = 0;
var paddingBottom = 0;
var paddingLeft = 0;
var yourFeature;

map.getView().fit(yourFeature.getGeometry(), { padding: [paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingBottom, paddingLeft] });
```